# Getting info.plist for enterprise IOS application

Tags: ios, plist, ipa

I am developing an IOS application through an enterprise account. This application will be set on a specific website to be downloaded. 
I archived the application from Xcode, and got the `ipa` file, but I still need the `plist` file.

Any idea how to get it?

Comment: your question is not clear. What you would  like to to with plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check mark option **include manifiest file** while creating ipa.So xcode will generate file for you. Otherwise you can get plist file from internet and edit according to your application

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i didn't get your question but if you want to access .plist file after archiving. You have to

1. Unarchive your iPA file.
2. It will create a "Payload" folder, inside it you will find .app file.
3. Right click on it, "Show package contents" and you can see your plist file.

Comment: how do I unarchive the iPA file?